# How to extract amount from a receipt email

Tags: email-parsing

I noticed many reimbursement apps can parse the amount out from a receipt email. Just curious what are the necessary steps to achieve that? Especially considering there is no pattern in the receipt email itself.

Since we have so many vendors, if we need parse email, do we need find patterns for each of the vendors? Seems not very scalable.

Comment: This question is likely to vague for StackOverflow. That said, most receipts do include enough information of a pattern to determine the amount total. Even just ignoring all character data and just looking for numbers would find the amounts, tax, totals etc. The biggest number would be the final total after taxes.

Comment: There must be a pattern. Please provide an example.

Comment: valid points. THanks